# Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)

Tags: permissions, ssh, public-key

I tried to connect to planetlab node using ssh. It throws me error like Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive). What does this mean?
Here is the verbose of the exception.

```
> OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL
> 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
> debug1: Applying options for * debug2:
> ssh_connect: needpriv 0 debug1:
> Connecting to planetlab1.csee.usf.edu
> [131.247.2.241] port 22. debug1:
> Connection established. debug1:
> permanently_set_uid: 0/0 debug3: Not a
> RSA1 key file /home/keven/.ssh/id_rsa.
> debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown
> key type '-----BEGIN' debug3:
> key_read: missing keytype debug2:
> key_type_from_name: unknown key type
> 'Proc-Type:' debug3: key_read: missing
> keytype debug2: key_type_from_name:
> unknown key type 'DEK-Info:' debug3:
> key_read: missing keytype debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
> key_read: missing whitespace debug2:
> key_type_from_name: unknown key type
> '-----END' debug3: key_read: missing
> keytype debug1: identity file
> /home/keven/.ssh/id_rsa type 1 debug1:
> Checking blacklist file
> /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
> debug1: Checking blacklist file
> /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048 debug1:
> Remote protocol version 2.0, remote
> software version OpenSSH_4.7 debug1:
> match: OpenSSH_4.7 pat OpenSSH_4*
> debug1: Enabling compatibility mode
> for protocol 2.0 debug1: Local version
> string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1p1
> Debian-5ubuntu1 debug2: fd 3 setting
> O_NONBLOCK debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT
> sent debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
> diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
> ssh-rsa,ssh-dss debug2:
> kex_parse_kexinit:
> aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
> aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
> hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
> hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
> none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib debug2:
> kex_parse_kexinit:
> none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib debug2:
> kex_parse_kexinit:  debug2:
> kex_parse_kexinit:  debug2:
> kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
> diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
> ssh-rsa,ssh-dss debug2:
> kex_parse_kexinit:
> aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
> aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
> hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
> hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
> none,zlib@openssh.com debug2:
> kex_parse_kexinit:
> none,zlib@openssh.com debug2:
> kex_parse_kexinit:  debug2:
> kex_parse_kexinit:  debug2:
> kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
> debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
> debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc
> hmac-md5 none debug2: mac_setup: found
> hmac-md5 debug1: kex: client->server
> aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none debug1:
> SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192)
> sent debug1: expecting
> SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP debug2:
> dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 128/256
> debug2: bits set: 508/1024 debug1:
> SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent debug1:
> expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
> debug3: check_host_in_hostfile:
> filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
> debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match
> line 1 debug3: check_host_in_hostfile:
> filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
> debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match
> line 2 debug1: Host
> 'planetlab1.csee.usf.edu' is known and
> matches the RSA host key. debug1:
> Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
> debug2: bits set: 535/1024 debug1:
> ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
> debug2: kex_derive_keys debug2:
> set_newkeys: mode 1 debug1:
> SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent debug1:
> expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS debug2:
> set_newkeys: mode 0 debug1:
> SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received debug1:
> SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent debug2:
> service_accept: ssh-userauth debug1:
> SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
> debug2: key: /home/keven/.ssh/id_rsa
> (0xb80c9878) debug1: Authentications
> that can continue:
> publickey,keyboard-interactive debug3:
> start over, passed a different list
> publickey,keyboard-interactive debug3:
> preferred
> gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,gssapi,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
> debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
> debug3: remaining preferred:
> keyboard-interactive,password debug3:
> authmethod_is_enabled publickey
> debug1: Next authentication method:
> publickey debug1: Offering public key:
> /home/keven/.ssh/id_rsa debug3:
> send_pubkey_test debug2: we sent a
> publickey packet, wait for reply
> debug1: Authentications that can
> continue:
> publickey,keyboard-interactive debug2:
> we did not send a packet, disable
> method debug3: authmethod_lookup
> keyboard-interactive debug3: remaining
> preferred: password debug3:
> authmethod_is_enabled
> keyboard-interactive debug1: Next
> authentication method:
> keyboard-interactive debug2:
> userauth_kbdint debug2: we sent a
> keyboard-interactive packet, wait for
> reply debug1: Authentications that can
> continue:
> publickey,keyboard-interactive debug3:
> userauth_kbdint: disable: no
> info_req_seen debug2: we did not send
> a packet, disable method debug1: No
> more authentication methods to try.
> Permission denied
> (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

Comment: This should be moved to serverfault.

Comment: I saw the debug output, but there's no evidence in the question of you trying to do this in a program (e.g. libssl, etc)

Comment: The SOLUTION in my case: Remove spaces around comma separators and everything will work fine. I was trying to get a `command="...` entry in authorized_keys to work.

Comment: There can be two issues in this case. 1. Permission to your private key is not proper i.e. permission is 000 or something which doesn't allow read or , 2. Permission to the remote machine's authorized_keys is not proper i.e permission is 000 or something which doesn't allow read ,, Solution would be to chmod 600 both these files permission. as per the deo's answer below

Answer (score 48):

You may want to double check the authorized_keys file permissions:

```
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Newer SSH server versions are very picky on this respect.

Comment: This answer should be featured. Almost every answer on the issue "Permission denied (publickey)" mentions the config, while this can actually also be the problem.

Comment: and the target user can't have group write permissions on it's home directory, this showed up in sshd's logs "Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/username"

Comment: There can be two issues in this case.
1. Permission to your private key is not proper i.e. permission is 000 or something which doesn't allow read
or , 2. Permission to the remote machine's authorized_keys is not proper i.e permission is 000 or something which doesn't allow read
                 ,, Solution would be to 
chmod 600 both these files permission.

Comment: In addition to this solution, I also need to change the .ssh folder permission:

chmod 700 ~/.ssh/

Comment: where is this file on windows?

Answer (score 39):

You need to change the `sshd_config` file in the remote server (probably in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`).

Change

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

to

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

And then restart the `sshd` daemon.

Comment: Finally! `PasswordAuthentication` was set to `no` on stock raspbian

Comment: do you mean after set PasswordAuthentication to yes, the problem is fixed?

Comment: If you're on Windows and getting the error `Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)`, `PasswordAuthentication yes` may not work as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67193433/unable-to-ssh-to-a-windows-machine-using-ngrok

Answer (score 11):

The server first tries to authenticate you by public key. That doesn't work (I guess you haven't set one up), so it then falls back to 'keyboard-interactive'. It should then ask you for a password, which presumably you're not getting right. Did you see a password prompt?

Comment: i set up the public key already. Plus, it doesn't prompt me for password at all.

Comment: Any resolution on any of this? I'm going through similar pain at the moment and hoped this question might draw some answers...

Comment: I accidentally set the wrong private key permissions (`--w-------`). Use `ssh-add -L` to show if you've set up a key and in case you haven't, use `ssh-add` to add it.