# Tried to install Hadoop - getting Permission denied errors

Tags: macos, hadoop, ssh

I followed [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Fully-Distributed_Operation) Hadoop tutorial here.

*My end goal is to install Hadoop and Spark, and what not on my Mac*, but honestly, I'm an amateur at this thing, at best.

So, I got up to step 2, under Execution of **Psuedo-Distributed Operation** and then the following appears:

```
sudo start-dfs.sh
Password:
2014-06-10 18:42:01.200 java[6982:1303] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
14/06/10 18:42:01 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 17:d5:20:eb:8d:f9:24:2f:c6:46:d7:e2:f5:6a:b8:c1.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
localhost: Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password:
Password:
Password:
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

Basically, I typed in my password for user lanceguinto, and it is apparently incorrect. Of note is that I did not follow the **Setup passphraseless ssh** portion because I thought it was unnecessary - I can already ssh, but I'm entirely sure that code does.

During the setup, I also simply used my local user. I did not sudo su / anything.

So, how can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps

```
You need to change the sshd_config file in the remote server (probably in /etc/ssh/sshd_config).

Change

PasswordAuthentication no
to

PasswordAuthentication yes
And then restart the sshd daemon.
```

[Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556056/permission-denied-publickey-keyboard-interactive)