# TeamCity ssh user

Tags: ssh, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm trying to run a script from Teamcity Agent on other environment (mac).
I am using script that contains 'ssh administrator@33.333.33.33..'
when running the script as administrator on the Teamcity agent environment it works (after I used the publicKey). when running the Teamcity project I'm getting

```
[Step 1/1] Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
[00:18:15][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 255
[00:18:15][Step 1/1] Step run protractor test (Command Line) failed
```

I've tried also adding the ssh key file to the project as seen here
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/SSH+Keys+Management

I'm still getting the error. I assume that maybe Teamcity Agent uses other user (than Administrator) to run the script.
any ideas?

Comment: TeamCity Agent uses the same user to run scripts as the user under which the Agent is running. Do you run the agent under the Administrator?

Comment: apparently I'm doing it as root. so I updated the public key, but now it seems like it doesn't find the script file. I'm getting  [Step 1/1] bash: run.sh: No such file or directory [04:15:42][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 127 [04:15:43][Step 1/1] Step run protractor test (Command Line) failed

Answer (score 0):

This may be of use, but is potentially not a "TeamCity" issue

[Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556056/permission-denied-publickey-keyboard-interactive)

Answer (score 0):

Script is run using the account which is running Teamcity agent service. You need to make sure this account has enough rights to run the script.

Comment: thanks. I think it is 'root' and I added public key also for that user. the problem is that now I'm getting

    [Step 1/1] bash: run.sh: No such file or directory
    [04:15:42][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 127
    [04:15:43][Step 1/1] Step run protractor test (Command Line) failed