# libssh - failed to connect to localhost

Tags: c, ssh, libssh

I have no idea why my libssh program fails to connect to the localhost but it works fine for remote host.

```
ssh_session my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, "my_user_name");
ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "localhost");

int rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
if(rc != SSH_OK) {
  printf("Error connecting to the localhost\n");
  exit(-1);
}
// Authorized by the password.
rc = ssh_userauth_password(my_ssh_session, "my_user_name", "my_password");
```

The program can successfully create the session but it always failed in the last line when I tried to get authenticated. The error message I got from `ssh_userauth_password` is `(Access denied. Authentication that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you see the config  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

change 
`passwordauthentication no`
to
`passwordauthentication yes`

refer: [Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556056/permission-denied-publickey-keyboard-interactive)